# How to format seconds value as a time string with simple JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a given number of seconds as a string (i.e. 120 = 2:00 minutes). I'm stuck with my code now and am getting the wrong answer. I'd like to use the code I already have, so please let me know if I can still work with it and just add to it or if I need to start over.

```
function prettyTime(num) {
  if (num < 60) {
    return console.log(num + "s");
  }

  var t = num/60,
      m = Math.floor(t/60),
      s = t - m * 60;

  if (num > 60) {
    mins = t + m;
    return console.log(mins + ":" + "00");
  }
}
prettyTime(123);
```

http://jsbin.com/UqoDEbo/1/

Comment: Any particular reason that [you're reinventing the wheel?](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: will the given time be always in seconds ?

Comment: Am I reinventing the wheel? I'm a total newbie to js. :D @ Matt

Comment: Yes, the given time will always be in seconds. @ Vedant

Comment: What's the purpose of the `t` and `m` variables? Can you explain?

Comment: This isn't your problem, but it's probably not what you want: you're handling cases when `num < 60` and when `num > 60`, but not when `num == 60`.

Comment: I was thinking I'd need to divide the given value by 60(seconds) to break it down into minutes. I can see now that m is a bit repetitive and that I don't need it. I was thinking hours, mins, seconds before.

Comment: Just go it through in your head: If `num` is `123`, then `t` is roughly `2`. Then you are dividing `2/60` which is a very small number. Hence `t + m` cannot give you the number of minutes. `t` already is the number of minutes (if you floor it).

Comment: Thanks Felix, I thought of that right after I posted here. Ha, trial and error!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function prettyTime(num) {
    if (num < 60) {
        return console.log(num + "s");
    }

    hr = Math.floor(num/3600);
    t = num%3600;
    min = Math.floor(t/60);
    sec = t%60;

    return console.log(hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
}
prettyTime(123);
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? What's the problem with his code and how does yours solve is? Please **explain** the problem and your solution, don't just post code.

Comment: *her code. This definitely works and I understand why, but yeah, please explain next time. I just want to make sure I do understand it fully. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vedant_Terkar/tn8HE/1/).

try this:

```
function prettyTime(num) {
    var secs=num;
    mins=Math.floor(secs/60);
    secs=mins?secs%60:secs;
    hrs=Math.floor(mins/60);
    mins=hrs?mins%60:mins;
    days=Math.floor(hrs/24);
    hrs=days?hrs%24:hrs;
    year=Math.floor(days/365);
    days=year?days%365:days;
    return console.log(''+num+' secs = '+year+' years, '+days+' days, '+hrs+' hours, '+mins+' minutes, '+secs+' seconds.');
   }
prettyTime(123);
```

as you're trying to get remaining seconds after converting them in minutes like: `s = t - m * 60;`

javascript has special:

`%` operator called as the modulo operator; it gives remainder `c =a % b` after division of `a by b` in `c`.
so in your case:
`m=s/60` and
`s=s%60`

`?:` is called ternary operator which is like this:

`condition ? true statements : false statements;`

means if condition `boolean expression` satisfies then evaluate `true part`; `false` otherwise.

Hope it'll help you. cheers..

Comment: Why should the OP try this? What's the problem with his code and how does yours solve is? Please **explain** the problem and your solution, don't just post code.

Comment: @FelixKling edited my answer have a look at that, is it okay now?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit better, but it still doesn't explain what's wrong with the OP's code.